# Do the 5 possible FusionTableLayer sum up to 500k possible rows?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I want to show more than 100k data points on a google map using the fusion table API.
Now I know that there is the limit of 100k rows from one fusion table.
[Google Spec](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)

But there is a possibility to add up to 5 fusion table layer as far as I understand.

So having the following limit:

> Only the first 100,000 rows of data in a table are mapped or included in query results.

It should be possible to sum up to 500k rows that can be displayed on a map.

Sadly, testing it it doesn't seem to work and the limit is still 100k data points.

But I still want to ask the experts around. Do you know for sure what is the limit of data points with multiple layers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is set to 100k datapoints since it's a lot for a browser to handle and manipulate without serious client processor load.

If the option is available for you, maybe you can combine multiple points into a single row by using a KML location entry for those points that qualify?

an example is setting the location field to:

```
<Point>
    <coordinates>-90.86948943473118,48.25450093195546</coordinates>
</Point>
<Point>
    <coordinates>-91.86948943473118,48.25450093195546</coordinates>
</Point>
```